# Linux : combining the "ls" and "cp" command

Tags: linux, shell

The command

```
ls -l | egrep '^d'
```

Lists all the Directories in the CWD..

And this command

```
cp a.txt /folder
```

copies a file `a.txt` to the folder named "folder"

Now what should i do to combine the 2 command so that the file `a.txt` gets copied to all the folders in the CWD.

Comment: By the way, `cp a.txt /folder` look for directory folder in `/`. It is very unlikely that you want to copy `a.txt` in several directories in `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cp` command does not take several destinations, but you could always try:

```
for DEST in `command here` ; do cp a.txt "$DEST" ; done
```

The command inside the backticks could be a command that produces a list of directories on standard output, but I doubt that `ls -l | egrep '^d'` is such a command. Anyway, the title of your question being about combining ls and cp commands, this my answer. To actually achieve what you want to do, you would be better off using `find`.

---

Something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "." -exec cp a.txt {} \;` may do what you actually want. The `find` command is a special case in that is has a `-exec` option to combine itself with other commands easily. You could also have used (but this other version fails when there are lots of directories):

```
for DEST in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "."` ; do cp a.txt "$DEST" ; done
```

Comment: What about folders with spaces in their names? Also, you don't extract the remove the extra info '-l' prints...

Comment: @jackrabbit actually there is worse, I didn't notice it was a `ls -l` command the OP had typed.

Comment: You could use find, but you would need the option to limit the search to 1 level deep.

Comment: `-maxdepth 1 -type d` gets you the first level directories.

Comment: That `find` command will also include a `cp a.txt .` which the op probably doesn't want.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use a wildcard instead.

You'll have to loop over the target directories, since `cp` copies to one destination at a time.

```
for d in */; do
  if ! [ -h "${d%/}" ]; then
    cp a.txt "$d"
  fi
done
```

The pattern `*/` matches all directories in the current directory (unless their name starts with a `.`), as well as symbolic links to directories. The test over `${d%/}` (`$d` without the final `/`) excludes symbolic links.